# How to run threads at the same time and access same resource in java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, filereader

Below I have written a runnable to run through a directory and parse the csv files in it. The current code runs so that both T1 and T2 read all the files in the directory. how do make it so that both T1 and T2 to run at the same time, but not access the same files to parse..

```
public class ThreadDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        executorService.execute(new Task());//T1
        executorService.execute(new Task());//T2
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String line = "";
            String dirName = "/dir/location";
            File[] fileList = new File(dirName).listFiles();
            BufferedReader br = null;
            for (File file :  fileList){
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getName()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    //parse few vaule
                }
                System.out.println("The file name is this :::: "+file.getName());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first split the array of `File`s into 2 subarrays and give one subarray to each task. Like this:

```
public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dirName = "/dir/location";
        File[] fileList = new File(dirName).listFiles();
        int mid = fileList.length / 2;
        File[] fileListOne = Arrays.copyOfRange(fileList, 0, mid);
        File[] fileListTwo = Arrays.copyOfRange(fileList, mid, fileList.length);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        executorService.execute(new Task(fileListOne));//T1
        executorService.execute(new Task(fileListTwo));//T2
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    private final File[] fileList;

    public Task(File[] fileList) {
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String line = "";
            for (File file : fileList) {
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getName()))) {
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        //parse few vaule
                    }
                    System.out.println("The file name is this :::: " + file.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the easiest one. If thread 1 has bigger files, the load won't be divied equally. Another way would be to keep track of what file is being worked on by which thread and skip that one.

Comment: I agree. If we had more threads (say 4-5) I would probably have one queue from which threads would pick up the next `File` to process.